# What kind of adapter do I need for these HDDs (picture)?

Tags: hard-drive, storage, adapter

What kind of adapter do I need for these HDDs to plug them via USB? I removed these HDDs from an old PC.

[image: HDD-Image]

Comment: Left is plain old IDE/PATA, right is SATA.  There are adapter kits that come with both (plus laptop connectors) and an external power supply that converts the stand alone drive to a USB external drive.

Comment: I haven't seen a PATA drive for many years.  I suggest rescuing the data off it to a modern drive or cloud, blanking the old drive, and giving the old drive to an electronics recycler.

Comment: Something like this is what you need, it does both PATA and SATA....https://www.amazon.com/AGPtek-Drive-Adapter-Converter-External/dp/B00BIE996S